# Cascade delete issue in EF 4.2 (code first)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an Entity called User. User should be used in multilingual environment
So User looks like

```
    class User{
 virtual ICollection<TextEntry> Name {get; set;}
 virtual ICollection<TextEntry> Info {get; set;}
...
}

class TextEntry
{
int id {get; set;}
string Text {get; set;}
string Culture {get;set;}
}
```

Also I have a rule for user

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(q => q.Name)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(q => q.Info)
        .WithOptional()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

With this rules EF could not create model 
Esception message is "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'User_Info' on table 'TextEntry' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.\r\nCould not create constraint. See previous errors."

Without this rules I get an exception when trying delete user, because of references constraints.

How it possible to solve this wihout creating additional entity for User.Info data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is from SQL Server, not from Entity Framework. Entity Framework is creating one table for both occurrences of TextEntry.

Probably the easiest solution is to derive from TextEntry two other classes, make TextEntry abstract and map these two to distinct tables ([TPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716779.aspx)).

Comment: But what if I will have 3 or more field which should be multilingual? I don't think that it's a great idea to create new instance for new field. Because it's all have the same functionality, but different names.

Comment: @Ph0en1x Yes true. But without creating the database outside Entity Framework with some custom parts (views [might help to mimic one table], triggers [might help to actually the cascading], etc.) you'll not move much further.

Comment: I really hope that this issue possible to solve with some trick with EF rules.

Comment: As @cincura.net stated it is a SQL Server error. This occurs when you have two objects/tables that specify cascade delete on both tables. However, these tables will reference each other. Therefore SQL Server just does not handle it. The best way to manually do the cascase delete on one side.